# Impossible to change any option in option inspector

Tags: options

I would like to enable AutoSave in the options.

However, all the options are grayed in Mathematica (see below) and I cannot change anything.
The software has been launched as administrator.

[image]

How can I fix such issue?

Comment: Choose "Selected Notebook" or "Global Preferences" (I don't know the exact French translation) instead of "Sélection" in the upper selector.

Comment: It worked. Thanks.